# d2007 set dependency to external program

Tags: delphi, dependencies

In d2007 ide I can indicate that one project depends on another project.

Is there a way to indicate that a particular file, depends on another file (neither of which is a delphi program) and which needs to run a specified program in order to convert it. In old make files I used to do this and it would be really helpful to be able to do it in delphi to further increase automation and minimize errors and external actions needed to complete some projects.

I suspect that the microsoft project manager that delphi uses is capable of this but I'd like to avoid manually editing the file when delphi can change it any time.

Comment: I think this will be a difficult task since IDE "owns" [MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd.aspx) file (`*.*proj`).

Comment: I cannot make sense of this. How exactly does one file depend on another? And how can a file need to run a program? That makes no real sense. Perhaps you could be less abstract.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: imagine a `.c` or `.asm` file that needs to be compiled into an `.obj` file for use in a `.pas` file. Obviously, the `.obj` needs to be compiled before the `.pas` file can use it. But Delphi cannot compile C, and does not have a command-line assembler of its own. But it would be possible to have Delphi invoke an external third-party compiler to compile the `.obj` for the Delphi compiler to then use. IOW, Joe wants to link files together so that when a given file get compiled, its dependencies are processed first to ensure their output is ready beforehand.

Comment: @Remy That might be it. It might be better to let the asker tell us what he actually wants.

Comment: To David Hefferman: An exe depends on every source file. If any of the source files change an recompile is required. There are other file types (home brewed or not) that are created by running a program based on a "source" file of some type. If that source file changes you want to run that program to re-create the end result file. Delphi xe5 for sure has this ability but I can't just switch to that from d2007.

Comment: Remy: I can't run things like upx and code signing in the final build because delphi still does some things to the file AFTer the final build runs -- especially if you use madexcept. It trashes the exe. Building it in a different project that depends on the original project seems to work right.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, you cannot define inter-file dependencies within Delphi (not sure about MSBuild). However, you can use project-wide Build Events to run external programs and scripts during Pre-Build, Post-Build, and Pre-Link stages.  For example, you could use a Pre-Build event to invoke your converter so that its converted output files are ready for the compiler to use as needed.

Comment: msbuild has support for dependency specification and processing, just like make or any other serious build tool

Comment: I don't use MSBuild myself, so I am not familiar with its capabilities, outside of how to specify target platforms.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is not available in D2007, but in newer versions you can configure a [Custom Build Tool](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Adding_a_Custom_Build_Tool) and link it to a file in the project. Taking Remys example, you would add the asm file to the project and link it to the proper assembler to produce the obj whenever the asm changes.

Comment: Good point, I forgot about Build Tools. And I think you meant my example, not David's.